# Having an array of points that form a circle how to randomize one coordinate?

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, pseudocode

We have an array or points (double's X, Y, Z) they form a circle, starting from default rotation angles Xa, Ya, Za. We  want to extend each point in our circle by one axes (say Z) on some random variable. How to do such thing in pseudocode?

Comment: `array or points (double's X, Y, Z) they form a circle` - That makes no sense.  Did you mean you have a circle in 2D space specified by 3 numbers (radius and x/y of center)?  Or a circle in 3D space specified by 3 variables (normal, radius, and center)?  Or they you have 3 numbers specifying a sphere?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - I think there's a typo (should be "array _of_ points," not "array or points"). OP means that they have an array of points in 3D that are coplanar and equidistance from some center point.

Comment: @Ted: I realize it's a typo.  But given the rest of the description, I don't think that's what he means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this (pseudocode):

```
void randomize(Point[] points, Axis axis, double scale) {
    RandomNumberGenerator rng = new RandomNumberGenerator();
    for (Point point : points) {
        point[axis] += scale * rng.nextRandom();
    }
}
```

If you need to displace points along some direction that is not an axis, you'd modify the above to compute the displacement vector components and add each component to the corresponding point coordinate.