# How to find a center of point3d array?

Tags: c#, .net, geometry, point

We have a Point3D[] - a points cloud. We want to find its center. How to do such thing, Here by center we mean  geometric mean?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Have you tried searching for an appropriate algorithm?

Comment: How do you want to define the center? Center of gravity, point of least-square distance to the other points, arithmetic mean, geometric mean...

Comment: Maybe you are looking at the center of the bounding box? Please define what you mean by center, and provide and example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you could use:

```
new Point3D(points.Average(p => p.X),
            points.Average(p => p.Y),
            points.Average(p => p.Z));
```

Comment: Asked for clarification from the OP below. It was unclear if he wanted the centroid or geometric center of the bounding box in his question.

Comment: I wondered about  geometric mean but in my particular case Average would do=) Thank you wary much.

Comment: Judging from OP's [other recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286555/having-an-array-of-points-that-form-a-circle-how-to-randomize-one-coordinate), they are looking for the center of the best-fit circle. This is, in general, not the same as the centroid.

Answer (score 3):

One can think of many different centers, which one do you want?

1. Center of the bounding box of all the points - You do this by finding the min and max points, which are then then corners of the box. The center of this box is then (min + max) / 2
2. Centroid of all the points this is NOT the same as the center above see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid). This, BTW is the solution given by Jon Skeet above.